# Records dupped on Nulls - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, duplicates

```
SELECT 
    a.Name, a.Eats, a.Drinks
FROM 
    xd_animals_test a
```

Result in

```
Name        Eats    Drinks
Elephant    NULL    Y
Elephant    Y       NULL
```

What is the best way to get one result ? 
ex

```
Name        Eats  Drinks
Elephant    Y     Y
```

This is my attempt which I'm not sure if it is the cleanest way. Is there another more efficient way of doing this ?

```
SELECT
    Names.Name, Eats, Drinks 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         Name 
     FROM
         xd_animals_test) names 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         MAX(name) AS Name, MAX(eats) AS Eats, MAX(drinks) AS Drinks 
     FROM 
         xd_animals_test) eatdrink ON names.Name = EatDrink.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation for your example:

```
SELECT a.Name, max(a.Eats) as eats, max(a.Drinks) as drinks
FROM xd_animals_test a
GROUP BY a.Name;
```

This assumes that you have at most two rows for each `name`, as in the example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

or

```
Select name,
    Case if exists(select * from table 
                   where name = a.name 
                       and Eats ='Y")
        then 'Y' end Eats,
    Case if exists(select * from table 
                   where name = a.name 
                       and Drinks ='Y")
        then 'Y' end Drinks ,
From table a
```